# Cache (large and static) data with class variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, memcached

First, let me explain the situation, I've got following:

A "Node" Class with following attributes:

- node_id   (unique)
- node_name (unique)

And a "NodeConnection" Class with following attributes:

- node_from
- node_to

We'll have around 1 to 3 million nodes and something around 3 to 10 million NodeConnections.

After the nodes and connections are imported once, they **won't change**.

On each request to the Rails-Application, we'll have to look up around 10 to 100 node_ids by possible node_names. And we have to lookup a few hundred to a few thousands node_connections.

We currently prototyped this without any caching (so, a LOT of database-queries) and response times were horrible (like 2 Minutes).
So we switched over to cache the nodes and connections via **memcached**.

Got a performance boost, but still lacking of performance. (Because we're calling Cache.read for every NodeConnection, that's a few thousand calls per request)

Now, we tried caching via **Classvariable** and got a huge performance boost. (Response times within a few hundred ms)

```
# Pseudocode below
class Node
  def nodes
    @@nodes ||= get_nodes
  end
  def node_connections
    @@node_connections ||= get_node_connections
  end
end
```

So, I'd like to ask about **Pros** and **Cons** of this solution.

Cons I've got yet:

- Every Rails instance has to build up its own cache (it's own ClassVariables) -> higher total memory usage
- Initializing the cache is time consuming (1-3 minutes), so we can't do this within a request

Any other solutions out there to cache large (>100MB) and static (data won't change during applications lifetime) data efficiently, so all rails instances within the same machine can access this cache very fast (!)?

Comment: Just an idea, don't know if it's good or bad -have you tried using a `Struct` instead of an actual class, or using a custom C binding ? That could improve performance, too

Comment: I'll have a look at. You may have some ressources to the C binding stuff?

Comment: other god-or-bad idea: write a little C app that serves the data on a local UNIX socket, and caches data itself

Comment: This would be a start : http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html

Comment: So you have Nodes and NodeConnections - sounds like they could be connected into a tree or graph? Would need more details to think about a data structure, which could hold those items. The reason: memcache is fast, but loading millions of caches seems to be slow. I would try to pack the Nodes and NodeConnections into a data structure and store the whole data structure inside memcache. The warmup could be done via initializers, loading-hooks and cron jobs (still like them for stuff like this).

Comment: It's a graph, yeah. Unfortunatly memcache will only store 1MB per item per default (for good reasons as I read it). Currently I'm storing items in blocks (like 25k Nodes per memcache item). But that's even 1k of memcache items and to much to read on the fly.

Current Solution:
Cache all data into memached and load into Ruby (via class-attributes) when a Rails instance is starting. Hacked a LookUpTable-Gem for this solution, but still some work TODO.

Cons for this solution:
* Memory-Usage -> This will Limit the number of Rails instances running on the server

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a very specific situation, but in order to avoid the need for a per-process in-memory cache (i.e. your class variables) to naturally warm up, I'd be investigating the feasibility of scripting the warm-up process and running it from inside an initializer... your app may take longer to start up, but your users would not have to wait.

EDIT | Note that if you were using something like Unicorn, which supports pre-loading application code before forking worker processes, you could minimize the impact of such initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the hint of unicorn. I'll give it a try. (One more reasone for unicorn: Had some issues with nginx and passenger)